# Disabling scroller making the wrapped items not to work

Tags: actionscript-3, flexbuilder

My requirement is to enable the scroller for an app if the height of the device is less than 1100. Here is the code for that..

```
 if( FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.height < 1100)                  
                    settingsScroller.enabled=true;
                 else
                     settingsScroller.enabled=false;
```

But disabling the scroller disable all the items that were wrapped with it. Is there any solution for this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please specify the type of settingsScroller ? also specify layout of SettingsScroller
like i use scroller as 

`<s:Scroller id="myScroller"
       top="10"
       bottom="5"
       left="10"
       right="10"
       skinClass="views.skins.scroller.MyScrollbarskin">

     <s:TileGroup id="myTileContainer"
         width="100%"
         height="100%"
         verticalGap="12"
         horizontalGap="35"
         paddingBottom="5"/>
    </s:Scroller>`

Comment: For which purpose Scroller is used? i can say that i use scroller for just vertical or just horizontal or both ( V & H scrolling) purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this will be helpfull to you

```
            if( FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.height < 1100)
            {                  
                settingsScroller.setStyle('horizontalScrollPolicy', 'off');
                settingsScroller.setStyle('verticalScrollPolicy', 'off');
            }
            else
            {
                settingsScroller.setStyle('horizontalScrollPolicy', 'auto');
                settingsScroller.setStyle('verticalScrollPolicy', 'auto');
            }
```

hope this will works.